# Have to extract data in CSV from TIFF file a/c to my shapefile, have the data of entire coordinates but I only want the data as per my shapeile

Tags: shapefile, geotiff-tiff, export, csv, raster-conversion

I have the meteorological data of entire globe. I have uploaded the .tiff file into the raster layer in QGIS. I have also uploaded a layer of my desired country in .shp file. Now, I want to have the meteorological data of my country. OR is it possible to export data from .tiff file according to my shapefile.
I am a beginner with QGIS.

Comment: You mention CSV in your question title and tags but there is no reference in your question body. Try the tool *Clip raster by mask layer* in the geoprocessibg toolbox.

Comment: You want the clip tool